# Select where date falls within range

Tags: php, codeigniter, select, date

Codeigniter/PHP:

This is my current db query:

```
$pass_check = $this->CI->db->select('code')->from('coupons')->where(array('title'=>'Booyah'))->get();
$pass_check = $pass_check->result_array();
```

There are two other fields: 'exp_date', and 'start_date'. These represent when the coupon should be available and when it should not.

How can I only select codes/coupons that fall within the applicable date range in the db?

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL statement to select values between two dates would be something along these lines:

```
SELECT code 
FROM coupons 
WHERE title = 'Booyah' 
AND CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN start_date and exp_date;
```

I'm sure you can make the appropriate substitutions for CodeIgniter.

> AKA, if the start_date is less than
>   today, don't get it, and if today is
>   after the exp_date don't get it.

But I'm assuming you meant "E.G., if today is less than start_date, don't get it, and if today is greater than exp_date, don't get it."

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
$today = today's date.

```
$today = date();    
$pass_check = $this->CI->db->select('code')->from('coupons')->where(array('title'=>'Booyah'))->$this->db->where("$date BETWEEN start_date and exp_date")->get();
$pass_check = $pass_check->result_array();
```